# Где взять все возможные DllImport для mono.dll?

Tags: c#

Подскажите где можно найти весь возможный DllImport список от mono.dll
Например

```
[DllImport("mono.dll")]
public static extern IntPtr mono_image_loaded(string name);
```

Comment: ```DllImport``` - всего лишь атрибут, указывающий на библиотеку динамической компоновки (DLL), из которой вызывается указанный метод (в данном случае ```mono_image_loaded```). Чтобы получить список просто имен методов, достаточно посмотреть в таблицу экспорта ```mono.dll```, - такой дампер пишется на коленке за пятнадцать минут. Если влом кодить, берете ```dumpbin``` - и вперед. А вод для того, чтобы получить параметры этих методов, потребуются отладочные символы. Хотя проще просто посмотреть исходники, ибо, если не изменяет память, проект ```mono``` опенсорсный.